# append globals to consuming applications .jshint file

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am writing an addon that wraps a third party library that uses globals and exporting them as es6 modules `export default someGlobal`.  The problem is that the consuming applications still sees the globals and complain during unit tests.

1. Is there a way I can insert these globals into the consuming applications .jshint file via a blurprint?
2. Is there a better way of exporting globals to es6 modules without actually modifying the third party code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve this using AMD modules.

```
// vendor/shims.js

window.DefaultGlobal = 'Hello';
window.AnotherGlobal = 'World'; 

//Shim as AMD module
define('YOUR_NAMESPACE', [], function() {
  'use strict';

  return {
    default: DefaultGlobal, //same as 'export default var DefaultGlobal = 'Hello';'
    AnotherGlobal: AnotherGlobal //same as 'export var AnotherGlobal = 'World'; '
  };
});
```

Then you can access it via

```
import {DefaultGlobal, AnotherGlobal} from 'YOUR_NAMESPACE';
```